# how to integrate keycloak with django and angular

Tags: django, angular, authentication, django-rest-framework, keycloak

i am using **keycloak** to login to my angular app instead of django rest API (simple token based authentication ) and i am following this below procedure and flow. so is correct? and i was using simple token(never expire) to for my django API from angular app, after implementing keycloak do i need to use jwt in angular app?

1. angular web page
2. click on login
3. went to keycloak login
4. login successful
5. and keycloak returned to angular app with access key, id token , refresh token etc..
6. what is the next flow , what i need to send to django API from angular app to verify the user if so how to do user.is_authenticated if user sigin up through keycloak because i dont have any user instance in my local django user model. what i need to send from django to angular my old token or keycloak token?
7. is there any django remote authentication required?
8. remote middleware required?
9. any help or suggestion please.

Comment: I dont know Django, but for Angular you could have a look at the OIDC lib from Damien Bod: https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client